# Getting only first rows AUTO_INCREMENT column value - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my code from my Codeigniter application where I'm trying to get a `location` by it's id.
The problem is that I can't get consistent results when retrieving the data.

**Model**

```
function get_location($id)
{
    $this->db->select('locations.id, locations.name_ka, locations.text_ka, locations.keyword_ka, locations.region, locations.latitude, locations.longitude, locations.notes_ka, locations.description_ka, locations.recomendation, locations.img, locations.nature, locations.culture, locations.resort, regions.region_type, regions.region_name_ka, resort.resort_name_ka, nature.nature_name_ka, culture.culture_name_ka, gallery.id, gallery.post_id, gallery.img_link, gallery.gallery_name_ka')
        ->from('locations','id=$id')
        ->join('regions', 'regions.id = locations.region','left')
        ->join('culture', 'culture.id = locations.culture','left')
        ->join('resort', 'resort.id = locations.resort','left')
        ->join('nature', 'nature.id = locations.nature','left')
        ->join('gallery', 'gallery.post_id = locations.id','left')
        ->where('locations.id='.$id);
        $queryo = $this->db->get();
        return $queryo->row_array();
}
```

**Controller**

```
function details($id){
    $this->load->view('templates/head');
    $this->load->view('templates/header');      
    $details = array(
      'location' => $this->Location_model->get_location($id)
    );
    $this->load->view('one_location', $details);         
     $this->load->view('templates/end');
 }
```

And there is problem: it gets 'id' only for first row. For other records getting everything but, not id. Says `'id' = NULL;`

**Output examples**

```
1st row: array(22) { ["id"]=>string(1) "1" ["name_ka"]=>string(28) "მწვანე ტბა"...
2nd row: array(22) { ["id"]=> NULL ["name_ka"]=> string(37) "ბაზალეთის ტბა"...
49th row:array(22) { ["id"]=> NULL ["name_ka"]=> string(59) "სახლ-მუზეუმი, მუზეუმი, "
```

I can't seem to find what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of duplication of id in multiple tables...

Use Code like that:

```
$this->db->select('locations.id as location_id, gallery.id as gallery_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Model

```
function get_location($id)
{
    $this->db->select('locations.id, locations.name_ka, locations.text_ka, locations.keyword_ka, locations.region, locations.latitude, locations.longitude, locations.notes_ka, locations.description_ka, locations.recomendation, locations.img, locations.nature, locations.culture, locations.resort, regions.region_type, regions.region_name_ka, resort.resort_name_ka, nature.nature_name_ka, culture.culture_name_ka, gallery.id, gallery.post_id, gallery.img_link, gallery.gallery_name_ka')
        ->from('locations')
        ->join('regions', 'regions.id = locations.region','left')
        ->join('culture', 'culture.id = locations.culture','left')
        ->join('resort', 'resort.id = locations.resort','left')
        ->join('nature', 'nature.id = locations.nature','left')
        ->join('gallery', 'gallery.post_id = locations.id','left')
        ->where('locations.id',$id);
        $queryo = $this->db->get();
        return $queryo->row_array();
}
```